# Java send instanceof as paramater

Tags: java, parameters, instance, instanceof

This might be a stupid question but I gotta know if there is a way to send the instance of a object to a method?

Like this:

```
    public class TestClass
    {
        public TestClass()
        {
            //Initialize
        }
    }

    public class AnotherClass
    {
        Instance!? mInstance;

        public AnotherClass(Instance!? instance)
        {
            mInstance = instance;
        }

        public boolean isInstanceOfTestClass()
        {
            return mInstance == TestClass;
        }
    }

    public class Main
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            AnotherClass a = new AnotherClass(TestClass);

            if(a.isInstanceOfTestClass)
                System.out.println("lala");
        }
    }
```

(Tried to make it wrapped as codeblock)

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding this. Objects _are_ instances of classes. What does `Instance!?` mean?

Comment: Maybe you want to use the `.class` attribute of the class?  It's hard to say without knowing what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

There's no such thing as an "instance of an object". An object is an instance of a class - so "instance" and "object" refer to the same thing.

You can use the `instanceof` operator to test if an arbitrary object is an instance of a particular class:

```
if (a instanceof AnotherClass) {
    // ...
}
```

There's also the class `java.lang.Class`, which represents the class of an object. You can get it by calling `getClass()` on an object:

```
Class<?> cls = a.getClass();
```

See the API documentation of `java.lang.Class`.

Comment: The particular method you want in "Class" is "isAssignableFrom", it's the more dynamic version of instanceof.

Comment: If I have a parent class Enemy and a child class Zombie that inherits Enemy. How can I then do Class<Enemy> mEnemyClass and assign mEnemyClass = Zombie.class?

Comment: `Class<? extends Enemy> mEnemyClass = Zombie.class;`

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use `Class.isAssignableFrom` and construct with an instance of Class where T is the class you want to test for.

But if you are bothered about about enforcing typing and making non-type specific classes I suggest you read up on generics.